# Which dinosaurs from the original Jurassic Parks survived until Jurassic World?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world

As established, [the T. Rex seen in *Jurassic World* is the original one from the first *Jurassic Park*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133825/19561).

**Did any other dinosaurs from any of the original *Jurassic Parks* survive?**

And did they survive the Indominus Rex massacre in *Jurassic World*?

Comment: As you said, the T-Rex big mama survived the encounters, so that is answered.

Comment: Wait, the T-Rex in Jurassic World is supposed to be Rexy? She's looking good in her old age, then.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Yeah, check the linked question for more details. That's what triggered this question.

Comment: related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35417/what-happened-to-the-dinosaurs-from-jurassic-park

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safe to assume that the T-Rex is the only survivor from Isla Nublar that is still on the island.  From the companion [website](http://uk.jurassicworldintl.com/), we can confirm that it definitely is the same T-Rex (also confirmed by the directer [here](http://uproxx.com/movies/jurassic-world-colin-trevorrow/)):

[image: T-Rex].

Based on the text from the website

> After all, she's been living on Isla Nublar for over twenty-five years!

and the fact that none of the other attractions boast that the dinosaurs have been around that long, it is a safe assumption that none of the dinosaurs on display are from the original Jurassic Park.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think anyone will ever know the lifespan of a dinosaur. I mean, they've been gone for way too long, even things like carbon testing aren't going to really help. With that said, some of those dinosaurs might have died off to old age, lysine deficiency, or carnivorous predators. If you look at the Lost World, it was shown that dinosaurs would flourish naturally, provided there aren't too many predators. What you get in Jurassic World, would be a combination of new clones and some dinos from the first movie, but there isn't really any way to tell. The T-Rex was the only one I saw mentioned as specifically coming back, because the rest didn't really matter. 
It could be assumed then, that all dinos who weren't killed off by predators would still be around now. The Irex's killing spree did stop eventually, but there isn't much way to tell at one point, tho he DID stop(talking to the birds/not killing the raptors).